# PHP error: Missing argument 1, even though I am passing a variable

Tags: php, oop

Even with the errors `var_dump` still works. Everything seems to work, but I get these two errors that repeat 4 times.

**Errors:**

> *Warning: Missing argument 1 for Product::__construct() in Product.php on line 13*
>
> *Notice: Undefined variable: attributes in Product.php on line 14*

**index.php:**

```
$products = $query->selectAll('products');

foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
    <li><?= $product->title; ?></li>
<?php endforeach;

$arr = [
    'type' => 'Furniture',
];

$furniture = new Product($arr);
var_dump($furniture->type);
```

**Product.php:**

```
class Product
{
    public $type;

    public function __construct($attributes) { // line 13
        $this->type = $attributes['type']; // line 14
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I had `return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Product");` from previous testing and just had to delete "Product" from it.

Errors are gone when I delete comment out this part of **index.php**:

```
$products = $query->selectAll('products');

foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
    <li><?= $product->title; ?></li>
<?php endforeach;
```

**selectAll() method:**

```
public function selectAll($table)
{
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$table`");
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Product");
}
```

Comment: You have not defined if $attributes is of array type or not, please define and you will not get these warnings

Comment: I can't reproduce the errors. Are you quite sure you're not instantiating Product somewhere earlier on without the variable? @Rahul type-hinting will not solve this.

Comment: The code you've shown as works as expected, without any warnings or notices.

Comment: Yes, agree what @Jiri Hrazdil says. Above works fine.

Comment: @MarkusAO see edit in OP. Those 5 lines were above where I declared $arr varaible. If I comment them out then there are no errors.

Comment: Do those 5 lines give you the error if you omit the `new Product($arr)`? There may be something odd going on in your `selectAll()` method, since the lines you post show no overlap with the Product class. Perhaps the code there is trying to instantiate the object without an argument (since it seems to return an array of objects).

Comment: @MarkusAO I added code for `selectAll()` method in edit.

Comment: @MarkusAO I had to delete `"Product"` from `return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Product");`

Comment: Yeah and there's what triggers your error, your PDO::FETCH_CLASS is instantiating `Product` without arguments. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want PDO to create a custom object instance you have to pass the constructor arguments. In [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) it is the third parameter:

> `public array PDOStatement::fetchAll ([ int $fetch_style [, mixed $fetch_argument [, array $ctor_args = array() ]]] )`
>
> [...]
>
> `ctor_args` Arguments of custom class constructor when the fetch_style
>   parameter is PDO::FETCH_CLASS.